# How do WSDL Web services Consume using Stored Procedure T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, wsdl

I want to consume simple wsdl webservices using T-SQL stored procedure for more security. How to use it. is it possible?

Comment: How is consuming a webservice from a stored proc going to increase security? Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Anyway but is it possible?

Comment: It is possible to call a webservice from a stored procedure but not at all advised. What have you tried?

Comment: Try this link. There are plenty of example. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+call+web+service

Comment: [Here is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913945/consuming-web-service-using-sql-clr-stored-procedure-not-find-default-endpoint-w) about a problem while implementing this solution - [read comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913945/consuming-web-service-using-sql-clr-stored-procedure-not-find-default-endpoint-w) to it which are mostly about why you shouldn't do this.