# Import JSON data into SQL from a REST API URL

Tags: json, sql-server

I want to download JSON data from a REST API URL directly into SQL Server.

I currently open the URL in a browser and copy the JSON data into a .json file which I save locally, then import using the following code. It would be more efficient if I could just query the URL from SQL server and return the same result.

```
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'C:\Users\taariq.AADDSGCX\Desktop\JSON\data.json', SINGLE_BLOB) JSON;
```

But I want something that replaces the local source with the URL. Example:

```
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK (OPENURL("https://restapidata.com/mydata"), SINGLE_CLOB) JSON;
```

Comment: SQL Server has no good support for directly accessing the internet, unless you count Azure SQL and the various ways it can use blob storage (but that's not quite the same thing). You can hack it together by using MSXML through `sp_oacreate`, but I strongly suggest you don't, as the error handling is abysmal and it's tricky to do it in a way that will not leak resources. If you just want to automate this sort of download, look at Power Automate, PowerShell or any other scripting language of your choice, but keep the HTTP access on the client side.

Comment: You are much better off pushing this through from Powershell etc. It's a really bad idea to access the network from the database engine. You could do something like `$json = Invoke-WebRequest ....; Invoke-SqlCmd ....`

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can use [Common Language Runtime Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/common-language-runtime-integration-overview?view=sql-server-ver15), e.g. write stored procedure which will request API URL and return its response data.

Some time ago I've placed the following question here - [Consuming web-service using SQL CLR stored procedure not find default endpoint while debugging with VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12913945/716684). I think you will find some important information for you reading discussion in comments there.